# Using a collection of an abstract type, or interface, as a Dependency Property of a UWP Templated Control

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, uwp, observablecollection

My model has two classes `ItemA` and `ItemB`, which implement the `ICustomControlItem` interface, and they are implemented as follows...

```
public interface ICustomControlItem
{
    string Text { get; set; }
}

public class ItemA : ICustomControlItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class ItemB : ICustomControlItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

My objective is to create a templated control `CustomControl` which has a (dependency) property `Items` which would be an `ObservableCollection<ICustomControlItem>`. An `ObservableCollection<T>` was used as I wanted the view updating when the collection changed.

Accordingly, the control is defined as follows...

```
[ContentProperty(Name = nameof(Items))]
public sealed class CustomControl : Control
{
    public CustomControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomControl);
        Items = new ObservableCollection<ICustomControlItem>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ICustomControlItem> Items
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<ICustomControlItem>)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Items), typeof(ObservableCollection<ICustomControlItem>), typeof(CustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<ICustomControlItem>()));
}
```

...with its XAML `ControlTemplate` containing a `ListView` to display the items of the `Items` dependency property...

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomControl">
    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding Items}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I used the following XAML to initialize and populate (with objects of both `ItemA` and `ItemB` classes) an instance of the `CustomControl` on a XAML Page.

```
<local:CustomControl>
    <local:ItemA Text="Item #1" />
    <local:ItemB Text="Item #2" />
    <local:ItemA Text="Item #3" />
</local:CustomControl>
```

At this point I expected all to be well, since both `ItemA` and `ItemB` implement the `ICustomControlItem` interface. However, Visual Studio keeps giving me a warning that reads...

> A value of type 'ItemA' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'ObservableCollection'

However, despite the errors, the XAML renders properly in the designer, and the application runs fine, but IntelliSense doesn't work in the XAML presumed by VS to be erred.

[image: Screenshot]

I doubt the issue is with the usage of the `ObservableCollection` because the errors don't occur when,

1. `Items` is an `ObservableCollection<object>` (however I need it to be constrained to the `ICustomControlItem` interface).
2. `Items` is an `ObservableCollection<string>` and `<x:String>` elements are added to the control.

How would this issue be resolved, and *a dependency property that is a collection of an abstract type, or interface*, be implemented?

Comment: Weird. I don't see any IntelliSense errors in my XAML in either VS or Blend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seemingly, the issue was a bug with the version of Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition (or one of its modules) that I had installed then. Updating the IDE (to `Version 15.2 (26430.14) Release`) resolved the issue.